# Gravar dados em API RestFul Laravel através de JSON

Tags: json, laravel, api, restful

Estou tentando gravar dados em uma API Restful em Laravel através de um JSON, mas eu não consigo gravar mais de um grupo de informações quando o arquivo tem mais de um.

```
"data": [    {
   "client_id": "3",
   "veiculo_id": "3",
   "carreta1_id": "3",
   "carreta2_id": "3",
   "motorista1_id": "3",
   "motorista2_id": "3",
   "embarcador_id": "3",
   "inicioprevisao": "2018-10-10 11:00:00",
   "fimprevisao": "2018-10-10 18:00:00",
   "nroliberacao": "3"
 },    
  {
   "client_id": "4",
   "veiculo_id": "4",
   "carreta1_id": "4",
   "carreta2_id": "4",
   "motorista1_id": "4",
   "motorista2_id": "4",
   "embarcador_id": "4",
   "inicioprevisao": "2018-10-10 11:00:00",
   "fimprevisao": "2018-10-10 18:00:00",
   "nroliberacao": "4"
   }
```

] }

Este é o meu Controller:

```
public function storeapi(Request $request)
{
  $array = $request->all();
    foreach ($array['data'] as $row) {
        return Sm::create([
            'client_id' => $row['client_id'],
            'veiculo_id' => $row['veiculo_id'],
            'carreta1_id' => $row['carreta1_id'],
            'carreta2_id' => $row['carreta2_id'],
            'motorista1_id' => $row['motorista1_id'],
            'motorista2_id' => $row['motorista2_id'],
            'embarcador_id' => $row['embarcador_id'],
            'inicioprevisao' => $row['inicioprevisao'],
            'fimprevisao' => $row['fimprevisao'],
            'nroliberacao' => $row['nroliberacao']    
        ]);
  }
```

}

Desta forma, o POST na função storeapi só grava o primeiro grupo de dados que tem no JSON, o segundo não grava. Segui este artigo para conseguir gravar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861486/laravel-5-6-bulk-inserting-json-data

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido. O problema era o return que tinha na chamada do create.

```
$array = $request->all();
$insertedIds = [];
    foreach ($array['data'] as $row) {
        $newSm = Sm::create([
            'client_id' => $row['client_id'],
            'veiculo_id' => $row['veiculo_id'],
            'carreta1_id' => $row['carreta1_id'],
            'carreta2_id' => $row['carreta2_id'],
            'motorista1_id' => $row['motorista1_id'],
            'motorista2_id' => $row['motorista2_id'],
            'embarcador_id' => $row['embarcador_id'],
            'inicioprevisao' => $row['inicioprevisao'],
            'fimprevisao' => $row['fimprevisao'],
            'nroliberacao' => $row['nroliberacao']    
        ]);
        $insertedIds[] = $newSm->id;
  }
  //Now we can return an array with the inserted elements' IDs
  //In this case, since this is coming from a JSON, we'll answer the same way.
  return response()->json($insertedIds);
```